# How to enable openedx teams tab?

Tags: openedx

I am trying  to enable Teams tab in openedx but i am not getting any option or any configuration in platform or in admin panel.
i got some info about teams creation but not getting any solution for enabling tab enter image description here
[enter link description here](https://edx.readthedocs.io/projects/edx-partner-course-staff/en/latest/course_features/teams/teams_setup.html#teams-overview)

Answer (score 1):

go to {LMS_HOST}/admin/waffle/flag/
Create a new waffle flag named teams.enable_teams_app and enable it by setting Everyone to True

Answer (score 0):

Please enable this on your Open edX installation.

```
ENABLE_TEAMS = true
```

You can find more flags [here](https://edx.readthedocs.io/projects/edx-installing-configuring-and-running/en/latest/feature_flags/feature_flag_index.html):

Comment: i have added it in config but i am not getting any options or toggle for team